# How to remove text outside tags xml

Tags: python, xml

I am a New User python and I am trying to manipulate a XML file. Where there is text outside the XML tags, only strings. As the example below:

`blhpxxxx [SCRIPT MODE]> show syslog server 1
Retrieving syslog server (s) ...
<EVENT
SEVERITY = "Repaired" />`

The issue is that I can not imagine how to remove all text that is not within the tag.

---

Sorry for the lack of details about my problem anyway as I said I am new to the python world , however , found the solution to the problem .

1 - The file that I get is not xml , it only contains xml tags in the middle of text. Here is a complete example of the structure :

HP BladeSystem Onboard Administrator
( C ) Copyright 2006-2013 Hewlett - Packard Development Company, LP

blhp0001 [ SCRIPT MODE ] > show syslog server 1

Retrieving syslog server ( s ) ...

Syslog Server 1 :

```
<EVENT_LOG DESCRIPTION="Integrated Management log">
 < EVENT
  SEVERITY = " Repaired "
  CLASS = " Rack Infrastructure "
  Last_update = " 05/15/2011 15:58 "
  INITIAL_UPDATE = " [NOT SET ] "
  COUNT = " 11 "
  DESCRIPTION = " Server Blade Enclosure Inadequate Power To Power On : Not Enough Power ( Enclosure Serial Number " , " Slot 6 ) "
 / >
 < EVENT
  SEVERITY = " Informational "
  CLASS = " Rack Infrastructure "
  Last_update = " 05/09/2011 24:18 "
  INITIAL_UPDATE = " 05/09/2011 12:18 "
  COUNT = "1"
  DESCRIPTION = " LAN Settings Changed ( USE844HBNT Enclosure Serial Number ) "
 / >
```

blhp0001 [ SCRIPT MODE ] >
show syslog server

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

prt = False

for line in open('meh').readlines():
    if 'EVENT_LOG' in line:
        if prt:
            print line.rstrip()
        prt ^= True
    if prt:
        print line.rstrip()
```

With this, I can delete all the text between tags is not, or is a tag.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: if there is text outside the tags then by definition it isn't an `xml` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the first comment points out, it actually isn't a xml file.

But you could use a short script with regex to create a xml file. Given your example string, you could create such a script based on the following code:

```
import re

text = 'blhpxxxx [SCRIPT MODE]> show syslog server 1 Retrieving syslog server (s) ... <EVENT SEVERITY = "Repaired" /> '

print(re.search("\<.*\>", text).group())
```

Depending on the structure of the surrounding text you may have to use a more sophisticated regular expression.

Comment: Hello crs,

Thanks for the help, I believe I will not need a complex regex, the file structure does not change much in this example. Thanks also for clarifying that my file is not xml.